# Do Angels reproduce?

Tags: genesis, angels

It seems that Angels were created in finite numbers without the ability to reproduce. The Genesis 6 wives were earth women. For the fallen angels to have children with them would mean possessing an earth man to uses their sexual organs.

Comment: Do they, did they or can they? Because if it’s “do they” the answer is no, currently they don’t, they are too afraid. And the other assumption you make is that they have to possess a human’s body or possess a human body, they already have a body, they don’t need another body.

Comment: Try searching for related questions on a specific to biblical text.  Then, you can ask questions about texts without the question already asked.  Here is an example of a question already asked: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/66497/we-are-told-about-nephilim-in-num-1332-33-why-might-some-interpret-them-as/66499#66499

Comment: Another example: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/56581/will-everyone-be-gender-neutral-in-heaven-and-if-so-does-that-mean-that-sex-wa/56614#56614

Answer (score 2):

What Jesus said here seems to indicate that the angels don't have the capacity to reproduce.

> For in the resurrection they neither marry nor are given in marriage, but are **like angels** in heaven.
> (Matt. 22:30, ESV)

> For when they rise from the dead, they neither marry nor are given in marriage, but are **like angels** in heaven.
> (Mark 12:25, ESV)

> The sons of this age marry and are given in marriage, 35 but those who are considered worthy to attain to that age and to the resurrection from the dead neither marry nor are given in marriage, 36 for they cannot die anymore, because they are **equal to angels** and are sons of God, being sons of the resurrection.
> (Luke 20:34–36, ESV)

Basically the argument is if the angels don't marry, would God give them the ability to bisexually procreate?  Why would God create them with a desire they couldn't fulfill?  Most certainly God wouldn't expect them to be promiscuous.

Comment: Good answer - "Sons of God" is an allusion to the OT idea that YHWH was the "Father" of them all Deut 14:1, 32:6, 18, Jer 31:9, Mal 1:6.

Comment: Jesus says they don’t marry, there is NO indication that they cannot procreate or that they don’t have the ability to inseminate. A single person is not also infertile. Granted to reproduce in God’s understand is to also be married but that doesn’t exclude the ability to procreate. Heavenly beings are all male and have no female counter part. That doesn’t mean they have no genitals it means they have no female equivalent to copulate with.

Comment: @Nihil Note "seems to indicate"

Comment: “don't have the capacity” note marriage doesn’t seem to indicate lacking capacity/ability

Comment: @nihil See edit.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions that don't ask about Biblical passages.

Answer (score 1):

This is *very* hard to argue using biblical reference points. There are the verses quoted in the other answers concerning *marriage* - but *arguably* this does *not* discount reproduction.

Reproduction requires *seed*. And if you accept the Genesis 6 account as *angels* procreating with earth women, then that may? provide basis for further arguments.

The other point is that there are no (OK, one possible/dubious/disputable in Isaiah) accounts of ‘female’ angels. So that’s a *possible argument against it.

Then there is Revelation 12 - Michael and *his* angels vs the Dragon and *his* angels … how did these ‘angels’ become theirs?

But, bottom line, there is no way to conclusively argue any position - but worse, those taking *either* position could sit there reasonably comfortably without necessarily needing to argue away contrary points of view - as their foundation is not ‘seen’ as solid.

Comment: I don't think it's difficult to find Biblical reference points.  I could have provided multiple other texts, but feel it is best to keep the answer simple.  When one knows the Bible well, it's much easier to see the connections among the various truths to be found in it.

Comment: Hi Dave, as an experienced user of the site we'd really appreciate your help in Voting to Close questions like this which clearly violate the BH.SE on-topic guidelines, rather than answering them, which encourages more low-quality questions.

Answer (score 0):

The old English translation of the Genesis 6 passage lends itself to some unfortunate misunderstandings.  The Bible is clear, in Jesus' words no less, that angels do not marry.

> For in the resurrection they neither marry, nor are given in marriage,
> but are as the angels of God in heaven. (Matthew 22:30, KJV)

And the Bible never mentions angels as male, female, husbands, wives, children, or babies.  As you suggest in the question, angels do not reproduce.

But in Genesis 6, the KJV translation says:

> And it came to pass, when men began to multiply on the face of the
> earth, and daughters were born unto them, That the sons of God saw the
> daughters of men that they were fair; and they took them wives of all
> which they chose. (Genesis 6:1-2, KJV)

This expression "sons of God" is a reference to the Godly men, which were those of the line of Seth.  They chose to marry worldly women, and it was this that corrupted their morals and those of their children.

> For as many as are led by the Spirit of God, they are **the sons of God.**
> (Romans 8:14, KJV)

Comment: I do not know why this was down voted - a perfectly good answer.  I have upvoted to balance it out. +1.

Comment: The Sethite hypothesis is a 2nd century AD fabrication that was popularized by Augustine in the 4th century AD not on principle or Biblical backing but merely on theological biased objections

Comment: @Polyhat Thank you for this well-reasoned response! +1

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions that don't ask about Biblical passages.

Comment: @curiousdannii  It asked about a Biblical passage (Genesis 6) and was therefore "on-topic" per your rules.

Comment: @Polyhat It's not really about Genesis 6. It just mentions it in passing.

Comment: @curiousdannii  You are the moderator, not me.  It's your prerogative to enforce rules per your standard of judgment; I have my own standard, however, as to which questions I will answer.  My purpose here is to help people learn the truth via sound Biblical hermeneutics.  I do not answer questions that, in my judgment, were asked merely to be provocative and not asked in sincerity.  The recent question about angels' genitals was one such that I ignored.  But I do not see it my place to judge the quality of each question.  I'm here to help answer. Please don't ask me to moderate in your stead.

Comment: @Polyhat - Actually, BH.SE follows a community site model, which works the opposite way round from how you describe it. [Site Moderators](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) are "exception handlers", and should intervene as little as possible. As users gain experience on the site by creating good questions and answers, they earn 'rep' and associated privileges for moderating the site. With your help, off-topic questions get flagged and closed, bad content gets flagged, and so the site is built on the community rather than one or two biased individuals (like me) :)

Comment: It's really not about judging quality. The site on-topic guidelines are very clear - in this case the question isn't about *'① the history of that biblical text itself or ② the meaning of that biblical text either in context or through a process of arriving at a particular interpretation of it are off-topic.'* It's just a wider topical question that isn't really addressed by the passage in any meaningful way. It's not that the question is *bad*, but rather that it doesn't fit with the site guidelines.

Comment: @SteveTaylor I appreciate your perspective.  As regards moderation, I simply don't have the energy for it.  I've been a forum moderator on other sites.  It's a thankless job.  I'd far rather leave that part to others here.  If my contributions are unappreciated without involving myself in the operation of the site more directly, I may prefer to back away.  It may be that in some future moment I'll feel more energetic; but now is not that moment.  To me, this is a leisure-time activity, not a job.  You're doing well here, though; thank you, and keep it up!

Comment: Sure, that's okay - as you say, moderation has its challenges! Feel free to contribute as much or as little as you'd like to the site in every respect - at the end of the day the site is a community, not a workplace, as you say :) But as an experienced user you're fairly well aware of the site's on-topic guidelines, so if you could at least not encourage off-topic questions by answering them, that would perhaps be a good opportunity to positively contribute to the site without expending additional time or energy.

Comment: @SteveTaylor As anyone viewing this question can see, three "experienced" members all answered it.  I saw it as on-topic.  I expect they did, too.  I will not be drawn into a debate on the nitty gritty of the rules.  If my idea of "on topic" differs from that of the moderators, how could the difference even be reconciled?  Again, I'm here to help people find hermeneutically sound answers to their sincere Bible questions.  I saw this as a sincere and legitimate question, and it was most certainly linked to Bible passages, albeit the rules don't actually require a Bible passage.  Enough said.

Comment: Any of you would have been welcome to add your votes to Close the question or keep it Open, or to Reopen it afterwards, but nobody did - the only three users who voted understood it to be in breach of the site guidelines. The [on-topic guidelines](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) were created before I joined this site and define the bounds of this SE - this gives us a common yard-stick to go by. Generally, any question closed today would likely have been closed five years ago - the Close reasons are specifically designed to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

This question is almost certainly too broad.

Can heavenly beings procreate? Do they have the capacity to inseminate a human female?

> “I will put enmity between you and the woman, and **between your offspring** and her offspring; he shall bruise your head, and you shall bruise his heel.””
> ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭3:15‬ ‭

Genesis speaks prophetically of a time that the heavenly beings will have offsprings.

What are heavenly beings?

> “Yet you have made him a little lower than the heavenly beings and crowned him with glory and honor.”
> ‭‭Psalm‬ ‭8:5‬ ‭

A heavenly being is just a little higher than a human. The distinction is that they are natural and above the natural or supernatural. So they can interact with nature and operate above the laws of nature

> “There are heavenly bodies and earthly bodies, but the glory of the heavenly is of one kind, and the glory of the earthly is of another.”
> ‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭15:40‬ ‭

There are only two types of bodies, natural or earthly and heavenly or supernatural bodies.

So the heavenly beings in Genesis 6 did not need to take on bodies of humans, they had bodies and they had seed/DNA. As such all they had to do was abandon their place in the heavens and forcibly impregnate a human woman.

> “And the **angels who did not stay within their own position of authority**, but left their proper dwelling, he has kept in eternal chains under gloomy darkness until the judgment of the great day—”
> ‭‭Jude‬ ‭1:6‬ ‭

If this doesn’t answer your question please let me know or if I need to connect the dots more also let me know.

Comment: Hi Nihil - yes, this question was clearly off-topic for a few different reasons. Please do Vote to Close any questions that don't meet the on-topic guidelines of the site.