# Will gender differences persist in heaven?

Tags: greek, jesus, paul, gender, heaven

Scientists have established that men and women *think* differently and reach decisions differently.  They tend to have different interests and aptitudes.  These distinctions go well beyond hair styles, dress, or anatomical differences--and reach the core of *being*, of what makes a person who he or she is.

Jesus made clear that marriage will no longer exist in heaven or the new earth.

> But they which shall be accounted worthy to obtain that world, and the
> resurrection from the dead, **neither marry, nor are given in marriage:**
> Neither can they die any more: for they are equal unto the angels; and
> are the children of God, being the children of the resurrection. (Luke
> 20:35-36, KJV)

Accepting that sexuality will no longer exist, with its anatomical distinctions, is there any further clue in Jesus' teaching that gender differences themselves might also be erased?

The Bible seems to indicate that we will know each other in heaven, even as we are known here.

> For now we see through a glass, darkly; but then face to face: now I
> know in part; but then shall I know even as also I am known. (1
> Corinthians 13:12, KJV)

Will we know men by their short hair, women by their long hair?  Will our masculine or feminine personalities be preserved? Will we still be *men* and *women* in heaven, even though we are no longer sexual beings, and will no longer be in marriage relationships?

---

NOTE: A related, but different, question is here.

[Will everyone be gender-neutral in Heaven, and if so, does that mean that sex was designed to be a temporary thing?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/56581/will-everyone-be-gender-neutral-in-heaven-and-if-so-does-that-mean-that-sex-wa)

Comment: We are not told so we do not know.  I think your linked question answers your question.  We are not told and do not know.

Comment: @Dottard You will note that I have tagged "Greek" as one of the things of interest to this question.  I've had only one course in it, and it's a complex language.  I know that "gender neutral" is one form of words in Greek.  Are there any such clues here in the language itself?  If not, the answer might be a simple "no."...and I would accept that.  As for your proposed question, that is not what I am asking--as you should have noticed from my explicit mention of that as being related "but different" at the end of my question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140859/discussion-on-question-by-biblasia-will-gender-differences-persist-in-heaven).

Comment: This is certainly a big question and probably one that there are other passages which could be exegeted to examine, but as presented seems like a clear duplicate - same passage, same question.

Comment: @Stevecanhelp That "duplicate" question had to do with physical, anatomical differences and sexuality.  My question has not a whit to do with sexuality, for I _know_ that will no longer exist.  This is not the same question.  That question asked if sexuality were temporary, to which the answer must be "yes."  It did not ask, as my question does, whether gender differences in thinking, personality, (voice?), etc. were temporary.  But thanks for closing it anyway.  I can see my questions are unwelcome here.

Comment: @Biblasia - why do you think your questions are unwelcome? Everybody has the occasional question closed, it's certainly nothing personal. We don't often have enough users on the Review Queues, so occasionally the Site Moderators need to chip in to the Close and Reopen queues to ensure decisions are made on a timely basis. This just seemed like a very clear overlap, feel free to post your concern on Meta for a better discussion with others on it, or else find a way to clearly differentiate your question from the other.

Comment: There is no point.  I tire of having to defend the eligibility of every single question I have posted here.  The mods end up rewriting them for me, or suggesting answers that aren't answer--as in this case.  It seems to require mind reading ability to be able to post here--as in reading the mods' minds to know what they will see in the question.  No room for individuality here seems to exist.  Because you cannot see the difference between the two questions, it does not exist.  There's no point in taking it to meta--it would be the same story there.